# Making landing pages with taxonomy

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to make about 100 landing pages using taxonomy.

I'm trying to stick to Drupal 8 core features as much as possible.

I created two taxonomy vocabularies, **Places** and **Main keyword**.

Now, what I want to do is create landing pages that consist of:

**1 place + 1 keyword**

**Places**

- London
- Paris
- Berlin

**Main keywords**

- Apples
- Oranges

Combinations (each of these is a landing page using tokens from both keywords in Views blocks [perhaps attached by Layout Builder] to make the page)

- London + Apples
- London + Oranges
- Paris + Apples
- Paris + Oranges
- etc.

What module(s) should I use to link taxonomy terms from two different vocabularies together like this (preferably, in an automatic way so the relevant pages are automatically generated when I add a new term in either vocabulary)?

I have been experimenting with Views and Layout Builder but I haven't come up with a solution yet.

**What I tried**

- I used the Views "taxonomy term page" view to override the taxonomy term pages; this lets me do what I want for a single term in a single vocabulary, but I want to use two terms in combination from two different categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How I'm doing this now**

1. Create a new content type, **Landing Page**.
2. Add two fields, an entity reference to *Places* and an entity reference to *Main keywords*.
3. Use Views blocks/Layout Builder to rewrite the HTML of the content type to show the text you want with the relevant keywords substituted in.
4. When you add a new term to either vocabulary, you have to create all the possible combinations manually by adding **Landing Page** content.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a custom view page that allows to filter with any taxonomy terms combined with depth.

Then create a path alias for each filtered page to hide the arguments.